# Show that $f$ is locally constant function.

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f: D \to C$ is analytic, Denote $f = u+iv$ and if $\exists$ an
>   $\mathbb{R}$ differentiable function $g: R \to R$ where $u = g\circ
>  v$. Show that $f$ is locally constant function.

My idea is to partial differentiate $u$ wrt $x$ and $y$ respectively and get $$u_{xx} =g_{xx}(v) \cdot v_{x}^2+g_x(v) \cdot v_{xx}$$ $$u_{yy} = g_{yy}(v) \cdot v_{y}^2+g_{y}(v) \cdot v_{yy}$$

And since $f$ is analytic, we know that $u,v$ are harmonic.

I tried adding up both equations and got stuck, any ideas on how to continue?

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Riemann and chain rule, we have $u_x=g'v_x=v_y$ and $u_y=g'v_y=-v_x$, where $g'$ is the real derivative of $g$. If $f$ is not locally constant we can find some point $z\in D$ such that $v_x(z)\ne 0$ or $v_y(z)\ne 0$. In any case we get a contradiction. (For example, $v_x(z)=0$ implies $g'(v(z))\ne 0$ and $v_y(z)\ne 0$. Thus, we can solve for $g'(v(z))$ and get $g'(v(z))^2=-1$, which is impossible since $g'$ is real.

Comment: Hi thanks. Would you mind elaborating on the contradiction